# Temporary drops in network in LAN

Tags: networking, router, lan, ping

I have several devices, including AP, router, Raspberry Pis and computers, connected to 8 socket 1Gb switch.

I have the following picture when pinging

```
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.31.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.31.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.31.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.31.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.31.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.31.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.31.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.31.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.31.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.31.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.31.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

I.e. ping is timeouting from time to time. This is observed between different pairs of independent devices. I have replaced cables and switch, so it is unprobable it is bad cables or bad switch.

Heavy traffic is also not probable, since network is not very loaded, i.e. no streaming etc.

Additional symptom is that this situation arises periodically, i.e. it can be long period of time with no problems but then they are starting again...

Please provide explicit possible reason and how to catch it?

---

Cables are short and of high quality. Wireless connections are also present.

Target device tried different. I.e. no common point in the problem, except Switch and LAN.

Comment: Are all connections wired ? How long are the cables ? ICMP used by ping is low priority and the first to be dropped in the event there is congestion on the network (are you sure there isn't?).

Comment: The low priority of ICMP also applies on the target. This is because ICMP is handled by the CPU, which is why Ping of Death -attack works. Literally everything else going on in the target system will take precedence, it will only respond when the CPU has time. So when you have these issues, check whether the target is actually doing something relatively CPU-intensive.

Comment: Could you have a routing loop? (ie multiple connections between 2 devices acting as switches?)  Can you confirm that this happens where packets dont go through wifi?

Comment: is there possibly a power saving mode in the switch, dropping packets as it needs to / is about to "power up"?

Comment: @davidgo how to check routing loop version?